# Constructor functions return statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, primitive

Can you explain me the differences between these two provided examples or provide me articles to read?

```
function x (){
    this.name="Diana"
    return [1,2,3]
}
let newOne = new x() // the return value is an array instead of the object

function ValString (){
    this.name="Diana"
    return 12
}
let newOneWithTheString = new ValString () // the return value is an object instead of the 12
```

Comment: Note that in JavaScript, an array is also an object.

Comment: @Ivar can you provide me article sources to read about this?

Comment: what? the fact that an Array is an Object? It's part of the javascript core design

Comment: @Diana - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a good resource. In this case, [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) talks about this behavior.